# What are some ways to describe disks sparkling with electricity? "Disks course with electricity"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, word-request

Like disks in [image: disks1] and [image: disks2]

What are some other ways to describe disks sparkling with electricity?
I think the description says "disks course with electricity," but I am not sure course has the meaning of "circled by running electricity." So I am not sure if I heard the description right. My understanding is "course" as a verb means run through. But I have never heard "course with electricity".

Comment: _I think the description says "disks course with electricity,” but I am not sure “course" has the meaning of "circled by running electricity.”_ **It doesn’t**. But _course_ **does** mean _run_, so the phase “discs course with electricity” describes the picture just fine. As for never hearing the phrase “course with electricity,” so what? There are plenty of phrases I’ve never heard before, but that doesn’t make them ungrammatical.

Comment: Besides, I just searched on Google books and found: _The street courses with electricity and computational force, transmissions of energy, information, materials, and goods._ Also: _My body courses with electricity, my heartbeat a huge drum in my ears._

Comment: Upvoted your comments. This seems to be a rare usage. I was actually also wondering if there are words that could replace "course" in this sentence, hence the "word-request" tag. Btw, I found the usage strange also because I couldn't find related definitions in Merriam-Webster and several other online dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "blood courses through my veins" - meaning blood runs/flows through my veins, is the immediate thing that comes to my mind with *course* - and perhaps the writer was comparing electricity to blood flow of a living person.

Of course the clearer way to say it and more obviously draw that parallel would be to say "electricity courses through the disks."

Some words to describe what electricity does would be *crawl*, *writhe*, *pulsate*, *wave*, *trace*, *lick*, etc.  There isn't a common word that directly describes the movement of electrical arcs, unfortunately.